# TP4056 charger module - Can we change the "Preset 4.2 V Charge Voltage" to 4.0 V?

Tags: lithium-ion, charger, module

I am using a [TP4056](http://www.tp4056.com/d/tp4056.pdf) charger module to charge a 2000 mAh lithium-ion cell (18650).

The source voltage is from a solar panel that generates a maximum voltage of 4.0 V. The TP4056 charging module is not cutting off, even after 2 days of charging, since it doesn't reach its preset 4.2 V (as per its datasheet.)

Is there a simple way to change the preset voltage to 4.0 V or less so that the charging module will cut off?

[image]

Comment: The minimum supply for the chip is 4 volts hence, you are using the device outside its recommended range. Don't do this is my advice. Use a boost regulator before the chip is my other advice.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy... Can you please suggest me a circuit...

Comment: I'd need a fuller specification of the levels from your SP to be able to do that. I'd also need to know what current you are using to charge the battery. Maybe you need to ask a new question?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no easy way to change it, not even a hard way, because it cannot be changed.

The TP4056 chip is manufactured with this limit and therefore can't be changed by modifying any external components on the module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply....